# android fail to show an alert dialog in Handler

Tags: android, multithreading

I tried to show a alert dialog in handler, but i could not show the alert. Could you help me have a look where is the bug?

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               myDialog.show();                       
               super.handleMessage(msg);   
    }   
   };

class myThread implements Runnable {   
   public void run() {  
       try {


           myHandler.sendMessage(message);  


       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

}

In onCreate:

```
    myDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    myDialog.setTitle("hi");
    myDialog.setMessage("thanks");
    myDialog.setButton("Next...",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

        }
    }); 

   new Thread(new myThread()).start(); 
....
```

I defined myHandler and myThread. Then in onCreate, I defined a dialog. And then call the mythread to run. I suppose the mythread will send a message to myHandler. Myhandler will then trigger the dialog. What is wrong with the logic? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you handler like this

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              super.handleMessage(msg);  

              String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");
                  if ((null != aResponse)) {
                          //Show dialog
                          myDialog.show();   
                     }
                 else{
                       // ALERT MESSAGE
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        "No message from Thread",
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }    

    }   
   };
```

and in your thread update like this

```
class myThread implements Runnable {   
   public void run() {  
       try {

                            Message msgObj = myHandler.obtainMessage();
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("message", msg);
                            msgObj.setData(b);
                            myHandler.sendMessage(msgObj); 


       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```